# Make div on ipad with overflow:touch to scroll in a same way as native containers

Tags: html, ipad, scroll

On ipad there is a css declaration -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch which provides fast bouncing scroll to any div with cliped content. But it has some differences against native ios scroll:

1. If it was never scrolled before (eg scrollTop property of parent div is 0) and one is trying to scroll it up, it doesn't bounce but scrolls a whole page up. Same situation for content scrolled to a very bottom and scrolling down.
2. If content insede scrollable container is smaller then container itself it doesn't bounce too but propogate scrolling to other elements up to the page instead.

Is there any way to make it behave exactly like the native ios scrolling, so touching the container will always scroll it but never the page.